# Recyclerview lagging in scrolling

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, android-recyclerview, android-asynctask

I'm trying to make a music app just to practice with Kotlin and I made a Recyclerview and function that fetches data from external storage.

Now my problem is that when I ever scroll up or down it keeps lagging and I think the reason is that in onBindViewHolder function I create a bitmap from the Uri by using this code

```
  bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(contentResolver,album_uri)
```

And then I set the bitmap

```
holder.song_image.setImageBitmap(songList[position].image)
```

I thought maybe if I create all bitmap all in once and place them into the Arraylist before I create the Recyclerview would help to stop the lag and it did but I had another problem that I can't deal with it in the main thread cause it freezes.

I didn't know what to use so I searched on what to use for that and I read about coroutines but I felt it's kinda for multiple threading/tasks with delay and what so ever but I just needed to do one simple task without freezing the UI Thread.

[image: Recyclerview]

Comment: Have you considered using an image-loading library, such as Glide, Picasso, or Coil? They can handle loading images on background threads for you and usually are very simple to integrate into an app.

Comment: Use Glide to load your images instead of bitmaps: https://github.com/bumptech/glide

Comment: big thanks, guys. It worked perfectly with Glide yeah. I didn't think that I will need a library but it saved me a lot of time. Someone put it as an answer please.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to use image-loading libraries like [Glide](https://github.com/bumptech/glide), [Picasso](https://github.com/square/picasso), [Coil](https://github.com/coil-kt/coil). They can load images on background threads.